# Reasons why I get this Error Message during execution of Eclipse´s Project Clean Option?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have the problem, that I get the following error message, if I execute the Eclipse IDE option "project / clean":

```
An internal error occurred during: "Validating my_maven_project".java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What could be the reasons, why I get this kind of error message. I don´t understand this.

Sometimes, this kind of error message are also visible, if I try to save something inside this Maven Project.

Thanks !

Comment: Check the contents of `your-workspace/.metadata/.log`, it may provide more info. Perhaps rename that to `.log-old`, then retrigger the error again and add the contents of `.log` to your question.

Comment: Post your `pom.xml`.